# ENC28J60 SS pin for Mega

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am trying to use ENC28J60 module (12 pins) with Mega. I connect it as it should and use Ethercard library and it works fine. I run all examples and have no problems. I just changed SS pin to 53 in driver. For some reason i need to use UIPEthernet library and with it i can not make module to work.

All wiring stayed i just tried UIPEthernet examples. None worked. Obviously my Mega can not communicate with module with this library, and my guess is SS pin. Which i can not find to change. I found on some places that SS pin for Mega is all ready declared, but then i must set in driver that i am using Mega and not Uno. I am not sure how to make it work.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=545579 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.